# In ASP.NET Web API 2 ExceptionHandlerAttribute throws method not found exception

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using `ExceptionHandlerAttribute` to handle exception in Web Api 2.

```
public class ExceptionHandlerAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public ExceptionHandlerAttribute()
    {    
    }     

    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        HandleException(actionExecutedContext);
    }

    private void HandleException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
       // Log exception here
    }
}
```

In one of the controller I have a async method below that throws exception (I know why this method throws exception but that is not question here)

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<OrderDTO>> GetOrders(FilterDTO filters)
    {
        return await _dbcontext.Orders
            .Include(x => x.User)                
            .Where(x => x.OrderDate > filters.StartOrderDate && x.IsApproved)
            .Select(x => new OrderDTO()
            {
                OrderID = x.OrderID,
                Amount = x.Amount,
                OrderDate = x.OrderDate,                    
                LastModifiedUser = x.User.ToDto()
            })
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

When exception occurrs in above method, Web Api framework invokes `OnException()` method of the registered `ExceptionHandlerAttribute` as expected. However within the filter i get `method not found error`

[image]

The `HandleException` method is private method in same class, i am not sure why its not finding the method?

**Update 1 (Stack Trace)**

> at XXXXXXXXX.Api.Filters.ExceptionHandlerAttribute.HandleException(HttpActionExecutedContext
>   actionExecutedContext)\r\n
>       at XXXXXXXXXX.Api.Filters.ExceptionHandlerAttribute.OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext
>   actionExecutedContext) in
>   C:\repos\XXXXXXXXXXXX\Src\Api\Filters\ExceptionHandlerAttribute.cs:line
>   30\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ExceptionFilterAttribute.OnExceptionAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext
>   actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: According to the exception message in the image it can't find `HttpActionExecutionContext.Request`. Show the exact message/stake trace as text and also include the body of `HandleException` method that was excluded from the code snippet.

Comment: Agree. but why its throwing exception while calling HandleException method? If you notice, i have debugger inside `HandleException`  on the first line. That debugger never hits. It does not even execute `HandleException` method, it throws error while calling `HandleException` inside `OnException`

Comment: Wont be able to say till I see the stack trace

Comment: see update1 above with stack trace

Comment: dumb question: you're sure, that the .net framework you're running your app with is properly correct installed and available? the app is running with the correct IIS runtime set?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the cause of this was? I'm getting the error in a Docker container running ASP.NET 4.6.2 and 4.7.2.